# How do I go from SKScene to UIViewController by code?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, segue, skscene

All I want if for when the user touches a skspritenode in the skscene, it will go to a different view like `performseguewithidentifier`. Thanks for any help. I can post code, but it seems like a generic question so I figured that you wouldn't need any. By the way, I already figured out how to detect the tapping the skspritenode. I have been looking at this for a long time and I am stumped. Please help.

Comment: Generic question, generic answer: the scene is part of the SKView which has an associated view controller. You can only segue view controllers. Therefore you segue from and to the SKView's view controller like any other UIViewController.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot present a viewController from within a SKScene as it is actually only being rendered on a SKView. You need a way to send a message to the SKView's viewController, which in turn will present the viewController. For this, you can use delegation or NSNotificationCenter.

**Delegation**

Add the following protocol definition to your SKScene's .h file:

```
@protocol sceneDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)showDifferentView;
@end
```

And declare a delegate property in the interface:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <sceneDelegate> delegate;
```

Then, at the point where you want to present the share screen, use this line:

```
[self.delegate showDifferentView];
```

Now, in your viewController's .h file, implement the protocol:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <sceneDelegate>
```

And, in your .m file, add the following line before you present the scene:

```
scene.delegate = self;
```

Then add the following method there:

```
-(void)showDifferentView
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"whateverIdentifier"];
}
```

**NSNotificationCenter**

Keep the -showDifferentView method as described in the previous alternative.

Add the viewController as a listener to the notification in it's -viewDidLoad method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(showDifferentView) name:@"showDifferenView" object:nil];
```

Then, in the scene at the point where you want to show this viewController, use this line:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"showDifferentView" object:nil];
```

Comment: The NSNotificationCenter thing worked perfectly. Thanks so much. I also used NSNotificationCenter for other parts of my app.

Comment: You're welcome. One final word of warning: don’t overdo it. Notifications are extremely useful but there might be scenarios where you are tempted to blast data out globally, when in reality you only have a single delegate that really is interested in the data.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the following option: (this goes in your scene)

```
-(void)presentViewController{

    MyViewController *myController = [[MyViewController alloc]init];
//Or instantiate any controller from the storyboard with an indentifier
[self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:myController animated: YES options: nil];
}
```

And later in your view controller, when you wish to dismiss it, do something like this:

```
-(void)dismissItself:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The good thing about this option is that you won't need to store your view since at any point you can initialize it as long as the scene you are in, imports the viewcontroller's code.

Let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

ZeMoon, nice answer, but what if multiple scenes want to show the same view controller, for example some settings screen? You don't want to define multiple scene delegate protocols that do the same thing.

Another idea is to define a single protocol which handles the presentation of different view controllers for you:

```
@protocol ScreenFlowController <NSObject>
- (void)presentSettingsScreenFromScene:(SKScene *)scene;
- (void)presentCreditsScreenFromScene:(SKScene *)scene;
@end
```

The scene parameter might be used to make decisions based on where you are coming from.

The view controller of your game (or any other object) implements the protocol. All scenes that display a different screen receive a weak reference to the controller:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ScreenFlowController> screenFlowController;
```