# SpriteKit / UIKit - Navigating between SKScene and View Controller

Tags: ios, uikit, sprite-kit, skscene, sklabelnode

I have a game with a menu screen. The menu options are SKLabelNodes in a scene.

My settings / options screen is in a view controller which containes UIKit sliders and switches.

What's the best way to link from a label node on the main menu to the view controller for the settings?

Thanks for any ideas :)

Comment: Only the "best way" or would "any way" suffice? :) This has been asked several times before (how to access view controller from scene/node). Here's one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22549255/how-do-i-go-from-skscene-to-uiviewcontroller-by-code/22555881#22555881 Check the related links, there's one answer that describes it well.

Comment: Perfect, my rushed lack of searching got me there. Thanks for the response :)