# Interface builder for SpriteKit

Tags: swift, view

I was wondering if it's possible to draw an interface using storyboard just like  for UIViewControllers but with SpriteKit.
I've saw this link which has something similar to this question: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28977467/how-do-i-use-storyboards-with-spritekit-using-swift)
I've also could present a SKScene converting the UIViewController's view (on loadView()) but when I do so, the view isnt recognized just like I've drawn on storyboard.
Is there any easier interface builder for SpriteKit or only by code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are .sks files that are included to provide a way to drag and drop your items directly onto the scene as if it were sprite-kit's "storyboard" of sorts. This can be for animations, buttons, anything graphical. There's a lot you can do there that will replace code as well.

Look at an example here -> [SpriteKit from Scratch Tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/spritekit-from-scratch-fundamentals--cms-26326)

The above tutorial entries from the same person shows you how to animate, reference, etc.

I haven't gone through them yet but if you're looking for Sprite-Kit's version of a storyboard that's going to be your best friend.