# I need to transition from a SpriteKit GameViewController to a regular View Controller in an iOS app (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, transition

I am making a game in Objective-C using SpriteKit, but there are also some view controllers. I need to transition from a SpriteKit scene to the non-SpriteKit view controller at a push of a button. The button is simply made of a SpriteKit Node, and can be pressed using this code:

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

    //if back button touched, show other view
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"backbutton"]) {
        //transition code goes here
    }
}
```

Now, I'm not quite sure what to put in the if statement that figures out if the back button is pressed. I have no idea, though I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22549255/how-do-i-go-from-skscene-to-uiviewcontroller-by-code/22555881#22555881). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the problem? The linked Q&A you have answers your question.

Comment: @sangony I'm not quite sure, it just doesn't work. I set up everything, and when I clicked the button, nothing happened. I even changed zposition to 5 to make sure it was at the top. I just figured that was the answer to a different issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one way of going about it would be to use the main.storyboard, actually. Have you tried setting up both view controllers that way? Let me know if this doesn't work:

You can actually use an 'Sprite Kit View Controller' and a 'View Controller' to fit your game. Set up the scene-transitioning button using the storyboard, and fit the rest of the game by using code. The button will be stuck there, so put it in a good place.

Merely set up a transition between the button and the 'View Controller' like you would in any Single View Application.