# iOS delegate issue when use it for second time

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am not an experienced app developer, I am modifying an obj c spriteKit game. The concept that I need to implement is, when the user clicks a button in the menu scene (SKScene) "talk" to the navigation controller and show another storyboard who they gave me.

For this I use a delegate from the scene, in order to "talk" to the gameview controller's navigation controller and reference the other storyboard.

Everything works, but when from the starting scene(EndGameScene in the code) the user goes to the gamescene and back then it does not work. And there is no error message!

**GameViewController.m**

```
SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = YES;
_scene = [[EndGameScene alloc] initWithSize:self.view.frame.size];
_scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
self.scene.delegate = self;
// Present the scene.
[skView presentScene:_scene];
...
//delegation method
-(void)showDifferentView {
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [SettingsViewController settingsStoryBoard];
SettingsViewController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:SettingsControllerStoryboardIdentifier];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
}
```

**GameScene.m**

```
-(void)backToHomePage{
[self removeAllChildren];
[self removeAllActions];
[self removeFromParent];

SKScene *endGameScene = [[EndGameScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
endGameScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
GameViewController *gameVC = [[GameViewController alloc] init];
endGameScene.delegate = gameVC; //when add that line crashes
SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition fadeWithDuration:0];
[self.view presentScene:endGameScene transition:reveal];
}
```

If I don't go to the GameScene there is no problem. The problem is when the user goes to the GameScene and comes back.

I would appreciate any help

Thanks

Comment: Where do your scenes live? EndGameScene is created an presented by GameViewController? Who creates and presents GameScene?

Comment: I am wondering why you create an instance of `GameViewController` and never use it apart from setting it as the delegate of your scene. Delegate properties are usually weak which means that they are not retained by the object that stores the property. This in turn means that you have to keep the object strongly referenced somewhere or it is released very soon after your above method returns and your delegate will not work.

Comment: GameScene is presented by the EndGameScene, I followed this answer to implemented http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22549255/how-do-i-go-from-skscene-to-uiviewcontroller-by-code. I gave a solution by using the NSNotification, but I cant understand the amistake in the logic with delegates. I am creating the instance in order to assign the delegate only

Comment: I added another answer to the thread you mentioned. All suggestions have a few things in common: your SpriteKit scenes should not present view controllers or trigger segues. Scenes should communicate their intent to show some other view controller to GameViewController (or any other object fit for the task), either by your own delegate protocol or notifications etc.